# Managing databases in Django models, sqlite and mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, sqlite, mongoengine

I'm developing some project in Django, something to manage assets in warehouses. I want to use two databases to this. First is sqlite database, which contains any data about users. Second is mongoDB database,in which  want to store all the data related to assets. The question is, how to tell to my model classes, which database they should use (models responsible for user registration etc - sqlite, models responsible for managing assets data - mongoDB)? I read about `DATABASE_ROUTERS` and using `Meta` classes, but it's solutions for supported databases by Django (or maybe I don't know something), I dont know if it's good and possible to integrate it with mongoengine.

Thanks for any tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, It's very simple. If you want your model to use mongoDB database, just create model class witch `Document` parameter (or `EmbeddedDocument`, for example `class Magazine(Document):`). but if you prefer default database type defined, just create class, like in django documentation (example `class Person(models.Model):`).

Comment: can you give a more detailed description? I'm with the same problem. What shall I do with the settings.py?

Comment: You don't have to make any additional stuff in your settings.py. If you want to create model for primary database (sqlite or mysql), create model class witch inherit models.Model, otherwise (model for mongodb) inherit Document (from mongoengine import *)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

I fully agree with to use database router. What I did is, I have used single admin interface to handle multiple databases. Note that authentication for all apps are stored in the default database.

Settings.py

```
# Define the database manager to setup the various projects
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['manager.router.DatabaseAppsRouter']
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'app1': 'db1', 
                         'app2':'db2'}

DATABASES = {
    #For login authentication of both app I have used postgres sql
    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
            'NAME': 'fail_over',                    
            'USER': 'SomeUser',                      
            'PASSWORD': 'SomePassword',                  
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                     
            'PORT': '',                      
    },
    # Set this parameters according to your database configuration
    'db1': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'yourdatabasename.db'),
    },
     # Set this parameters according to your database configuration
    'db2' : {
      'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
      'NAME' : 'my_database'
   }
}
```

Sample Models

```
# Create your models here for app1.
class Modelapp1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    field2 = models.TextField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'app1'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.field1
# Create your models here for app2.

class Modelapp2(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'app2'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.field
```

Comment: It's very nice solution, but not in my case. I'm using `mongoengine`, no `django_mongodb_engine`, so in my `settings.py` there is no mongodb configuration in `DATABASES` section. My Django version is 1.10, I won't use 1.5, because it's not supported. Details in [link](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/)